# highcharts legend middle ie7

Tags: highcharts

I'm stumped by a highcharts+ie7 problem. For some reason, my legend shows up in the middle of the chart (see below). It looks fine in FF, Chrome, and newer versions of IE.

When I change verticalAlign to 'top', the legend moves nicely to the top, but resetting verticalAlign: 'bottom' puts me back in the middle. Any Thoughts?

See image:

[image: Example]

Comment: Take look at: http://jsfiddle.net/g4X7t/show/ looks fine in IE7, which version of IE7 and Highcharts do you have?

Comment: It took me longer than it should have to figure it out, but the problem was purely a function of the way ie7 zooms. At 100%, the chart looks fine.